# Posting chatter feed with an image using a flow

Tags: visualforce, process-builder, visual-workflow

Is it possible to post feed with an uploaded image ( which is loaded as static resource) along with some text on to the feed.

Let's say user has been created on which chatter feed need to be posted with the image.
Is this possible using Process builder or Visualflow or some other way??

Comment: I am trying to think of doing it through Process builder, but I can add only group and merge fields in Immediate actions.